# What version to choose?

Tags: android, android-version

When installing the SDK i read something about 97% of phones support Android 2.1
My question is should i, when opening a new project choose to compile it to Android 2.1?
Will apps written for 2.1 work in newer version?
Will the opposite work? if i develop to 4.0.3, will it work in older?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is should i, when opening a new project choose to compile it to Android 2.1?

What you specify as your build target ("choose to compile it to") has no direct effect on what versions of Android can run your application.

> Will apps written for 2.1 work in newer version?

For any reasonable interpretation of the word "for", yes.

> if i develop to 4.0.3, will it work in older?

As with Agarwal's answer, this depends on what you mean by "to".

For example, suppose that you want to use `CalendarContract`. This class was added in API Level 14 (a.k.a., Android 4.0). So long as you *only* use `CalendarContract` on Android 4.0+ devices, you will be fine. If, however, you try to use `CalendarContract` on an older device, you will crash, because that class will not exist in the firmware.

Hence, you can *conditionally* use newer APIs, so long as you ensure that you only use those newer APIs on devices running a newer version of Android. Typically, this is done via a version guard block, something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // do something that requires API Level 11+ here
}
```

Comment: Right on. Thanks for the very specified answer.

Comment: But for some reason i cannot run a simple ICS HelloWorld app on 2.2. Any ideas why?

Comment: @BojanKogoj: No, because you have not provided any symptoms beyond "cannot run", which can have many different meanings. Feel free to ask a question here on SO. If the app is crashing, include the stack trace.

Comment: I've heared that Google play shows apps according to your versions, so will that not mean that they wont see the app in the market? is there any truth in that?

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Your manifest, particularly your `<uses-sdk>` element, will control what devices will see you on the Play Store. Your choice of build target does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop to 4.0.3 then it wont get installed on older version devices.
If you develop for 2.1 it will work fine on newer versions. But if you use you cant get 4.0.3 features .

Comment: That depends completely upon your definition of the word "to".

Comment: What about the opposite? Will an 2.1 ( or 2.2 which is more common?) work on a new device?